# Error: Expect status [308] from Google Storage. But got status 503

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have an app that has been running for several weeks but this morning it started receiving a lot of 503 error messages from Google Cloud Storage.

My app has not changed so could this possibly be a temporary issue on Google App Engine?

**Error:**

> ServerError: Expect status [308] from Google Storage. But got status 503

Some headers:

```
Request headers: {'content-range': 'bytes 10485760-10747903/*', 'x-goog-api-version': '2', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, *'}.
Response headers: {'alternate-protocol': '443:quic', 'content-length': '0', 'via': 'HTTP/1.1 GWA', 'x-google-cache-control': 'remote-fetch', 'server': 'HTTP Upload Server Built on Feb 3 2014 23:37:46 (1391499466)', 'date': 'Thu, 06 Feb 2014 12:06:11 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}.
```

Answer (score 1):

Support says they are having issues with uploads of files > 10MB right now